# Authentication in MVVM pattern

Tags: php, mvvm, frameworks

I am using a simplistic MVVM framework that I have created in PHP with a frontend index.php that routes all the communication (this approach works great for me).

The question I am grappling with is - where does user authentication take place in an MVVM framework? Do I implement it in the ViewModel or elsewhere? I am looking for a language agnostic answer, but even a language specific answer would do if the concept is clarified.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, by the process of elimination I'd say its in the ViewModel (can't be in the view because that's just a presentation layer and can't be in the model because you need to determine authentication before you actually know whether you should load the model).

Answer (score 0):

Think about the ViewModel this way, if it should be tested it likely goes in the ViewModel. That's not to say that you can't test your Model classes, but the meat of testing will be for your ViewModel classes. That being said, you really have two options. Either you could implement the authentication logic in your ViewModel and if it is the only ViewModel that needs the login info then I'd suggest that. However if you have multiple ViewModels that need to know whether the login was successful or not, it would be better to create a static class in your Model layer. This way, that authentication logic and login information could be given to any ViewModel that needed it.

Comment: Could it possibly in the BaseViewModel, then it would be inherited by all the ViewModels?

Comment: If each ViewModel will be authenticating separately, then yes that'll solve it. The static class in the Model layer is just if you want one ViewModel to do the authentication but all ViewModels to see the result.